# Asp.net 1.1 migration practices?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5, asp.net-4.0

I have an unconventional legacy asp.net 1.1 web app that uses the src attribute in the page directive that utilizes JIT compile on the server as supposed to the normal compile of assemblies in Visual Studio 2003.  We are approaching performance capacity limits of the 32-bit platform it's on and would like to migrate to a 64-bit capable asp.net version.  I'm unsure of the best migration path to take: migrate to 3.5 or 4.0?

What are the pros and cons of going with either version?  Is 3.5 in the process of being phased out?  Is 4.0 established enough for high-traffic web sites in production environment?  Does the same web app in 4.0 require more CPU and Memory resources than in 3.5? (new server needed?)

Thanks!

Comment: There is a MSDN Magazine Article that goes into a lot more detail on the process and the steps you need to take: *[Migrate Your ASP.NET 1.1 Apps to Visual Studio 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/ff956194.aspx)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at this:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/894435

You will either migrate to 2.0 first or do a complete re-write. The main jump is from 1.1 to 2.0 and you need to do this manually. You can easily use the VS wizard to then convert to 4.0. Forget 3.5; it was an interim release and the config files are horrible.

As for your dev env, note that VS will remain 32-bit for a long time to come.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had already begun the work of going from 1.1 to 2.0 manually. Just wasn't sure if I should be going directly to 4.0 or not.

Answer (score 1):

Both are very production worthy. It is your choice whether you can live with or without the features ASP.NET 4.0 gives you.

Answer (score 1):

To address one specific point:

> Is 3.5 in the process of being phased out?

.NET 3.5 is a system component of Windows 7 and 2008 R2: therefore it will be supported until those OS's go out of support. This is currently 2018 for Server 2008 R2 (see [here](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/?p1=14134)).